# class method returns wrong number in Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, oop, class, methods

I'm writing a mini game to learn Python. I created a weapons class that can be imported into my main.py file.

Here is the class I made:

```
class weapon(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.weaponName = name

    def weaponStrength(self, level, strength):
        self.weaponLevel = level
        self.weaponStrength = strength
        damage = self.weaponStrength * level

        print "Damage is equal to %r" % damage

        return damage
```

Here are the objects that are created using the weapons class.

```
# Creates an Object called sword using the weaponsClass
sword = weapon("sword")

# Calls a method of the weaponsClass to calculate weapon Strength. Returns a int
sword.weaponStrength(3, 20)

# Creates an Object called Magic Staff using the weaponsClass
magicStaff = weapon("Magic Staff")

# Calls a method of the weaponsClass to calculate weapon Strength. Returns a int
magicStaff.weaponStrength(5, 30)


# Sets a variable
swordStrength = sword.weaponStrength

# Sets a variable
magicStaffStrength = magicStaff.weaponStrength

# Prints the variable
print swordStrength

# Prints the variable
print magicStaffStrength
```

I'm trying to figure out why the swordStrength and magicStaffStrength are equal to the strength value passed to the method.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A side note: its more maintainable and clean to separate side effects from your weaponStrength() function.  That is, weaponStrength() should be renamed to something like damage() as that is what it returns, and the print function should be removed altogether. This should help alleviate the fact that your self.weaponStrength attribute has the same name as your self.weaponStrength() function.

Comment: I'd also point out, given your structure here, you probably mean to have a `set_characteristics` function that sets strength and level, and a `get_damage` functions that gets the damage.  Or if the characteristics are not meant to change after they are set, you could just have a straight member variable that gets set in the `set_characteristics` call.

Comment: @hexparrot I put the print function in there to view the value since it was wrong when I set the swordStrength variable. I'm going to remove it and make the changes mentioned by sr2222. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @sr2222 You're right. That will make it much cleaner. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're overwriting weaponStrength in the `weapon` namespace:

```
self.weaponStrength = strength
```

and

```
def weaponStrength(...):
```

are actually conflicting. Maybe think about your naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

This method is attempting to do two things:

Storing the weaponLevel and weaponStrength

Calculating and returning damage

I think this is a bad design, since the first purpose suggests the function should be called something like `setWeaponLevelAndStrength` while the second suggests it should be called `calculateDamage`. `weaponStrength` is obviously a terrible choice of name if you also wish to have an attribute with that name

```
def weaponStrength(self, level, strength):
    self.weaponLevel = level                #first purpose
    self.weaponStrength = strength          #first purpose
    damage = self.weaponStrength * level    #second purpose

    print "Damage is equal to %r" % damage  #second purpose

    return damage
```

I'd suggest you split the method into two

```
def setWeaponLevelAndStrength(self, level, strength):
    self.weaponLevel = level
    self.weaponStrength = strength

def calculateDamage(self)
    damage = self.weaponStrength * self.weaponLevel

    print "Damage is equal to %r" % damage

    return damage
```

Comment: You're totally right. I'm going two clean it up by creating to methods for the class instead of one. I appreciate your input.